# Regular expression design for ammunition calibers

Tags: php, regex, sorting, woocommerce, product

I need your help solving a problem that I am having sorting a large number of inventory items from an API into an online store.

The problem I am having is that a lot of the items are ammunition and they are categorized as such but I need them to be sorted into specific calibers.

The tool I am using to import them and categorize them supports regular expressions so I would like to see if I can solve this problem that way. While I only know the basics of using regular expressions I currently have no idea for how I would go about doing something like this. I was thinking I could extract the calibers from the titles as they are often included in there.

A couple examples of titles that the expression might need to sort through:

- Federal Cartridge Classic Buckshot 16ga 2 3/4" 1
- Winchester Ammo USA 5.56MM (223) 55Gr. FMJ/20
- Federal Cartridge 7.62x51mm 149gr FMJ /500

I would appreciate any help or guidance that I could get from you guys. It would save me a lot of time if I can sort this via Regex.

```
Edits / Expectation from the title: 

Federal Cartridge 7mm RemMag 150gr SierBTSP VtSh/20 -> 7mm, 
Winchester Ammo SupX 38 SPL Smokeless Powder , -> 38 SPL
Federal Cartridge 300 Sav 180gr SP Power-Shock /20, -> 300 Sav 
Winchester Ammo USA 5.56MM (223) 55Gr. FMJ/20, -> 5.56MM
Winchester Ammo SupX 45 Colt 255Gr. Lead RN/20, -> 45 Colt
Winchester Ammo SupX 12ga 2.75″ 7.5-Shot HeavyGam, -> 12ga
Winchester Ammo SupX 22LR #12-Shot Rimfire /50, -> 22LR
Winchester Ammo SupX 7.62X39 123gr SP/20 -> 7.62x39
```

I hope that is a little easier to follow. Sorry for the late follow-ups. Work has been eating my time.

Comment: When you say you need the titles sorted, *how* exactly do you need them sorted? I assume you want the ammo name in one group and the caliber in another? What about the other info? It would really help if you can showcase the desired *output* along with the input. Also, have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far? Seeing previous attempts (even if they're wildly inaccurate) would help us work out what your desired result is.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I actually have 0 idea on where to start in all honesty. Which is why I asked.

Comment: @mickmackusa Unfortunately the data does not contain that. I'm seeing if I can use regex to make this column or add to the data if that makes sense.

Comment: I can help you, but I need more and better info.  Show me a range of input values (like 10 or 20) then show me your expected result.  Just to clarify, you want to "reorder" the data, or "filter" the data?

Comment: Ervin Please edit your question to include these details then delete your comments.  Future researchers will expect to see the full story revealed in the question body.  Furthermore, it is hard to read/separate your commented strings.  Be sure that you express your EXACT desired output from your sample input -- if your question is not clear, you will receive no or poor answers. Do we get to know the API that you are using? We would better understand your question if you show your best coding attempt.  See the very first comment (from Obsidian)

Comment: @Ervin have you lost interest in this question?  I'll offer one last time... I am happy to offer a regex solution if you will kindly make your question more detailed/clear.  Please comment at me after you improve the question with all of the requested details.

Comment: @mickmackusa No. I've just been super busy with work.

Comment: How does this perform on your actual data? https://regex101.com/r/uVq3W1/2/ are there any "outliers) that I need to adjust for?  Please show me how you are going to code this up with php so that I can show you how to best implement (in case I can improve your process).

Comment: @mickmack This works, I just needed to add a few more calibers after messing with it and getting a good idea of how it worked. I don't know how you Regex guys do it. Thank you! If you could make an answer for the person who would be googling this years down the road that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Geez, you must really be busy with work.  I was worried you weren't coming back.  I'll post an answer for you in a few hours.  If you can show me a few more calibers, I'll bake it all into one expression.  (Just so you know, you must type my full screenname to ping me - because my handle doesn't have any spaces) I think I was alerted merely because I was the last commenter.

Comment: @mickmackusa Good catch thank you! Yes I have this mountain that I've been wanting to take down since I came back from vacation a little under a month ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex pattern can be written like this (there are several correct ways to do this):

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uVq3W1/3/

```
~(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?|mm|x\d+)|\d+(?|ga|lr| Sav| Colt| SPL))\b~i
```

Or logically split like this to help you see the grouping:

```
~
(?:
  \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?|mm|x\d+)
  |
  \d+(?|ga|lr| Sav| Colt| SPL)
)
\b
~i
```

The `\b` metacharacter is a word boundary which ensures that larger words that beginning with a desired string are not matched.  (You don't want to match `1 splash`)

The `i` pattern modifier (at the end) forces the regex engine to match case-insensitively.

`(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group and `(?| ...)` is a branch reset group.  https://regular-expressions.mobi/branchreset.html?wlr=1  Effectively, these are used to maintain the pattern logic.

A `+` is a quantifier that means "one or more" of the preceding expression.

A `?` is a quantifier that means "zero or one" of the preceding expression.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.  This will will perform a like comparison search of your titles against a per-compiled array of calibers.  The output will be an array where each key is the caliber that was found.

In order for this to work you will have to create an array of the calibers you expect to find. You could probably even find a pretty comprehensive list out there you could convert to an array easily enough.

Anyways, here you go.

```
$titles = array(

  'Remington 7.62x51mm 149gr FMJ',
  'Horandy .45cal HP',
  'Federal Cartridge Classic Buckshot 16ga 2 3/4" 1',
  'Winchester Ammo USA 5.56MM (223) 55Gr. FMJ/20',
  'Federal Cartridge 7.62x51mm 149gr FMJ /500'

);

$calibers = array(

'7.62x51',
'.22',
'.45',
'9mm'

);

foreach($calibers as $caliber){

  $results[$caliber] = array_filter($titles, function ($item) use ($caliber) {
      if (stripos($item, $caliber) !== false) {
          return TRUE;
      }
      return FALSE;
  });

}

print_r($results);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [7.62x51] => Array
        (
            [0] => Remington 7.62x51mm 149gr FMJ
            [4] => Federal Cartridge 7.62x51mm 149gr FMJ /500
        )

    [.22] => Array
        (
        )

    [.45] => Array
        (
            [1] => Horandy .45cal HP
        )

    [9mm] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: I'll see if the plugin i'm using supports PHP functions. If so that would be awesome. I would otherwise need create that manually.